# What is the 'arity' of a relation?

Tags: relations

On [wikipedia's 'Arity' page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) I noticed the statement,

> The arity of a relation (or predicate) is the dimension of the domain
>   in the corresponding Cartesian product.

I do not understand what this means and do not see an explanation on that page.

**What is a relation's corresponding Cartesian product?**

**What is the dimension of this Cartesian product's domain?**

Comment: It is how many variables the relation takes. Most commonly it is 2.

Answer (score 2):

It is the number of inputs to the relation or predicate.  The term is also used with functions, while I have not seen relations with other than two inputs.  The relation "less than" needs two values to make a complete sentence such as $x \lt y$, so has arity two.  The function $\sin$ takes one input to make a value like $\sin x$ so has arity one.  The distance function in $\Bbb R^3, \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ takes three inputs, so has arity three.

Answer (score 2):

By [definition](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29):

> an $n$-ary relation on $n$ sets, is any subset of Cartesian product of the $n$ sets.

so, as an example:
$$
R_1(x,y,z)=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2\ge 1\}
$$

is a  relation of arity=$3$